# Redirect wrong url laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5

Route :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('login');
});
```

and then try to visit this link:

http://www.example.com/wrongurl

How to redirect to specific page if someone trying to access wrong url thats not listed on router ?

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201305/redirect-when-route-doesnt-exist-laravel-4

Comment: Though the above url is related laravel 4, you can do the same in laravel 5 as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Handler. In the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file you have to add two lines of code in the `render` functions:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    if($e->getStatusCode() == '404') {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add as last route this:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function($any){
    redirect('/')'
})->where('any', '.*');
```

This will redirect any missing get route to /.

Answer (score 1):

If you have learned to use controllers. This will help.

```
Route::get('/home',Pagecontroller@homepage);
Route::get('/aboutus',Pagecontroller@aboutus);
Route::get('/contactus',Pagecontroller@contactus);
.
.
.
/*last route should be for the unknown url*/
Route::get('/{any}',Pagecontroller@indexpage); //this will redirect to the index page if any unknown routing url is given by mistake or by purpose.
```

**'/{any}'** will read all other url which is not declared.

**make sure that you use it at the end, after declaration of all other valid routes**

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code in Exception Handler file i.e. `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($this->isHttpException($exception)){
        if ($exception->getStatusCode()=='404') {
            return redirect('/');
        }else{
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }else{
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```